# If my android library created using latest AGP and kotlin version will it cause any issue while using old AGP and kotlin version?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-library

For example:

If I use AGP 7.4.2 and kotlin version 1.8.0 for building my android library.
While using in an app that uses AGP 7.1.* and kotlin 1.6.0. Is it going to cause any issue?

AGP 7.4.2 and kotlin version 1.8.0.

While building android library should I stick to old AGP and kotlin versions?

Comment: The Gradle Plugin rather not, but Kotlin version can be an issue. Read about Kotlin forward compatibility. Libraries often use the languageVersion and apiVersion options (defined in gradle) to avoid compatibility problems.

Answer (score -1):

Update your AGP version, there should be no problem.